# Connect to OPC-UA server from container-ized client app

Tags: .net, docker, asp.net-core, opc-ua

I have software I'm trying to write that needs to connect to an OPC-UA server.  The software is being hosted inside of a docker container and the OPC-UA server will ultimately be the one embedded in the PLC that my company uses.  For now I'm trying to use the Prosys OPC-UA Simulation Server running natively on my Windows PC.  I'm using the latest version of Docker Desktop with WSL2 mode turned on (instead of using Hyper-V).  This is a .NET application (.NET 6) using the OPCFoundation.NetStandard.Opc.Ua nuget package to handle communication to the UA server.  I can also confirm that the XML configuration file that the .NET UA library reads is in the location the software is expecting it to be in (root of the EXE).

Running outside of the docker environment I can connect perfectly fine with the connection string of `opc.tcp://<my_windows_ip>:53530/OPCUA/SimulationServer` to the Prosys UA server.  Once I create a docker image and create a container and try to connect to the server it fails.  I've tried

- host.docker.internal for the hostname
- The Linux 172.17.0.1 address (that is supposed to be the host PC's address)
- The Prosys connection string as is

  - opc.tcp://<fully_qualified_computer_name>:53530/OPCUA/SimulationServer
- 127.0.0.1 (which I expected wouldn't work anyway)
- Trying different port mappings in the `docker-compose.yml` file
- Connecting to an actual PLC that has an embedded UA server

Every attempt has failed.  I tried to rule out OPC by writing a really simple TCP listener app that was running natively on my computer and added an ASP.NET route to the app contained in docker that sent a message via TCP to the one not running in docker.  I had it listen to `0.0.0.0:13000` and my app hosted by a docker container connected to it fine.

I've been at this for almost a week now and I have no idea what to do next.  It surprised me that I couldn't connect to an actual PLC that has its own server in it.

Comment: If you can run Wireshark (https://www.prosysopc.com/blog/opc-ua-wireshark/) on the host and see, if it shows any messaging happening between the client and server that might help. In case the client makes a Discovery (FindServers) first, and uses those results, it might get wrong address to connect to from the server itself.

Comment: @JouniAro
This got me where I needed to be looking.  It turned out that connection was actually being made to the UA server.  The problem came from the user in the Linux container not having appropriate permissions to create folders and write files to the file system for the certificates sent by the server. I'll get an answer written up when I have more time.  Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out that the client was connecting to the server when trying to create the session.  The issue had to do with the Docker image.  We're using Linux images for the containers with the compiled program getting copied into the images `/app` folder.  We also add a user within the image.  That user didn't have write permissions to the `/app` folder.  That meant the OPCUA API that I'm using was unable to create the folders and write the certificate sent from the server to the file system.  A `System.IO.IOException` was being thrown.

I changed the ownership of the `/app` folder to this created user (recursively  as well) and made sure that the user had both read and write permissions on the folder.  Once I did that everything was working.